# Alfred Workflow to open a file in vim in the terminal

Tags: macos, vim, alfred

How can we write an alfred workflow to open a file from finder to a vim editor?

This is my first attempt to create a workflow in Alfred.
I am still learning and wanted to start with a simple workflow.

Here, I first created Hotkey and Keyword.

```
Open the Alfred3
Go to Workflows
Click + sign at the bottom left sidebar
Choose Blak Workflow
Name: Vim Launcher
Description: Opens a file in the terminal inside vim editor

1. Right-click > Trigger > press cmd-alt-v 
2. Right-click > Inputs > Keyword > open in vim  and title also open in vim

3. Right-click > Actions > Run NSAppleScipt
```

The copy and paste following contents inside `Run NSAppleScipt`

```
on alfred_script(q)
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "vim '" & q & "'"
    end tell
end alfred_script
```

This workflow works but opens two terminals instead of one.
How can we fix this make so that it opens only one window?

The workflow summary is given below.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a [Terminal Command](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/workflows/actions/terminal-command/) action.

Just connect this object to your triggers and use `vim "{query}"` on it.

EDIT:

I'm editing the answer to reply a comment asking a follow-up question:

> The workflow now create new termnial for each file, can we make it open in the same terminal if a terminal is already running?

In this case the `Run NSAppleScript` object could be used with the difference that we have to specify a location where `do script` should run, since it always open a new window if no location is specified:

```
on alfred_script(q)
    tell application "Terminal"
        if not (exists window 1) then reopen
        activate
        do script "vim '" & q & "'" in window 1
    end tell
end alfred_script
```

Comment: Are you sure adding bash script with above command will open the given file in the terminal with vim? It didn't work for me.

Comment: @astro123 yes, I am. I did the test. Can you share a link for your workflow as a comment and I point out what you did wrong?

Comment: Sure, what I did is given here, Please check: https://github.com/bhishanpdl/Shared/blob/master/Alfred-workflows/VimLauncher.alfredworkflow

Comment: @astro123 It's working for me. You just have to connect the triggers (`File Action` and `Hotkey`) to the `Terminal Command` object.

Comment: The workflow now create new termnial for each file, can we make it open in the same terminal if a terminal is already running?

Comment: @astro123, I've edited the answer with the solution.